# Java API doesn't recognize method

Tags: java, scala, implicit

While coding Scala, I am asked to use some Java library functions to finish the works. I was importing `java.time.LocalDate` lib and want to use its `plus` (years, months and days) functions, but seems to me that sbt is not happy with it:

```
value plusYears is not a member of object java.time.LocalDate
```

I checked the API some many times and I am pretty sure it wasn't any typo issue. In addition, my own functions that used the `LocalDate` were written as implicit functions. Any hint or insight that helps me debugging the program is appreciated.

```
LocalDate.plusYears(period._1 // Parameter of type Int )
```

Comment: Just an idea: this class `java.time.LocalDate` was introduced in Java 8. Maybe you're using your lib with older Java version?

Comment: @AndrejIstomin I don't think that's the case cause I also use other methods and they work fine.

Comment: Show the code which is failing to compile.

Comment: Look up difference between static and instance methods in Java. `plusYears` is an instance method and it makes no sense to write `LocalDate.plusYears(...)`: _which_ date do you want to add years to?

Answer (score 2):

You should get a LocalDate instance in order to invoke its instance(not static!) method. For example, `LocalDate.now.plusYears(3)`

Answer (score 0):

In this context, LocalDate seems to refer to the Java class `java.time.LocalDate`. perhaps `new LocalDate().plusYears(...)` will work?

Comment: That won't work. SBT would say there is no constructor in LocalDate. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: The thing is while using the `of` function, which is also a lib function in time.LocalDate, it works fine without any other casting, just like `LocalDate.of(...)`